# In Domino, can we find out if a particular person in names field is online on sametime by using JAVA or Lotusscript?

Tags: java, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, sametime

In Domino, can we find out if a particular person in names field is online on sametime by using JAVA or Lotusscript?

Help really appreciated.

Regards,
Yogesh

Comment: I think you need [IBM Sametime Toolkit SDK](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/toolkits.html). Check [IBM Lotus Sametime Java Toolkit Tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/sametime/80x.html), for example - chapters 5 and 7.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov you should probably make your comment as an Answer, I agree this is the best approach overall.

Comment: @ProgrammerDan I think a good answer should contain a particular solution for the described task. I just gave some guidance, not a real solution.

Comment: Of course. I suppose I was assuming you would expand it. I certainly understand if you have no interest in doing so!

Comment: @ProgrammerDan it is all about time, to write and check the necessary code :) I think OP can deal with my guidance and solve his task :)